# Get classes in a directory with PHP

Tags: php, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

Is there a way to obtain a list of all classes that implement a certain Interface inside a directory?

Comment: Sure, with [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis). Any more questions?

Comment: I think the answer by Jeff below is a great answer if you just need a simple one time check ... if you want to write a script to do it in php though, you can achieve it with two functions ... scandir() and class_implements()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory:

```
grep 'implements {x}' *
```

That should do it.